# How to query a relationship object using Emberfire?

Tags: ember.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, emberfire

I am creating a simple flash card app. The model is simple each user has many cars.

The problem is I would like to get cards which are created before a certain date (JS milliseconds).

```
model() {
    const session = this.get('session').content;
    return this.store.query('user', {orderBy: 'uid', equalTo: session.uid})
        .then((records) => {
            return records.get('firstObject');
        }).then((userData) => {
            return userData.get('cards');
        });
}
```

I can get all cards belong to a user use the snippet above, but **how can I get cards only meet certain conditions**? (For example, get cards which are created before certain date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
model() {
    const session = this.get('session').content;
    const now = Date.now('') + '';
    return this.store.query('user', {orderBy: 'uid', equalTo: session.uid})
        .then((records) => {
            return records.get('firstObject');
        }).then((userData) => {
            return userData.store.query(
                'card',
                {
                    orderBy: 'updatedAt',
                    endAt: 1481641085721
                });
        });
}
```

I try to query again on the `userData` to meet my requirement.